# .NET 4.0 to 4.6 and Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, tls1.2

We are moving to .NET 4.6.x to take advantage of default TLS 1.2 support.
We are currently on .NET 4.0

I read that the upgrade to 4.6.x is an in-place upgrade so little if anything needs to be done but I have a question about the web.config settings.

**We are explicitly referencing .NET 4.0.**

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=11111111111" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

Anything I need to do here? Just curious if web.config overrides the version of .NET selected in IIS, ect.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you create a new .NET 4.6 web application using Visual Studio, then compare that to your current project and see what you need to change?

Comment: Do you have the source code?  If you update the target framework in Visual Studio the web.config changes will be automatically updated during that process and you can re-deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change version

```
<system.web>
        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" targetFramework="4.6.x" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.x" />
</system.web>
```